# Serch in Active Directroy not showing some of the Users

Tags: search, active-directory, ldap, active-directory-explorer

I have installed AD DS on a Windows server 2016 and imported 1600 Users, 200 OU and 3000 groups. When I try to search using an LDAP Browser all the LDAP objects using the filter objectClass=User I getting only some users. I'm using an Enterprise Admin to do the search but I'm not getting all the objects. There could be problems of policies? what could it be?
Thanks

Comment: How many objects are returned? have you allowed the search to return enough objects?

Comment: How can I change the limit for the search? Is something that has to be set on AD or on my LDAP Browser?

Comment: The LDAP Browser should have a setting.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to retrieve over 1000 entries from AD, you should use Paged Results Control(RFC2696). It is enabled on AD by default.

In the case of ldapsearch command, "-Epr=<size>" give you the option with Paged Results.

I don't have LDAP Browser so I don't know whether it has Paged Results function or not, but I googled and found the following URL regarding Paging Results on LDAP Administrator.

Paging Results Overview
https://www.ldapadministrator.com/resources/english/help/la20191/ch06s06s01.html